# More than one consumable items in Amazon in app purchase for android

Tags: android, json, amazon-web-services, in-app-purchase

I'm implementing amazon in app purchase in my android application. I've downloaded their sdk and get sample project for in app purchase from that sdk. I've created two items to purchase in my amazon account and got json file from there. 
Now json file has two items in it. its json is like that json(I've removed some real values from amazon).

```
{"com.remove.adis.snt":{
"smallIconUrl":"",
"title":"Remove Ads",
"price":1.49,
"itemType":"CONSUMABLE",
"description":"Are you annoyed of ads!!!\r\nHere is the solution.Please buy this feature to remove ads from your app."},
"com.premium.doofun.snt":{
"smallIconUrl":"",
"title":"Premium Sounds",
"price":1.99,
"itemType":"CONSUMABLE",
"description":"Get More Sounds of interesting Categories like Action, TV, Entertainment, Love, Movies etc. to have more fun!"}

}
```

Now the problem is that its in app is working for one item only. If i continue by keeping both items in my json file it won't work. I need to remove one of these two to make it work. I'm stuck here,I couldn't get the idea from api too. Please help,any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you posted is invalid.  It has an extra comma after the last sub-object.  If this is just a posting error, then no idea.

Comment: yes, it was my invlid json and i also needed to change sku. thanks